# Scrambled Songs

Tags: letter-sequence

I've used quite a simple algorithm to create the appearance of a jumbled up bunch of letters. These letters represent a song. What is the song title?

> ## TTLSHIWWYAUATWSHLADITSTTLSHIWWYA

(Everyone should know this song, unless you live in a non-English speaking country.)

Comment: Seems to be from http://thesurvivalpodcast.com/forum/index.php?topic=23865.25;wap2

Comment: As a closely-related question, how about TTLBHIWWYAUATWYFLATTITSHIWWYA
 Hint: Ask Alice, I think she'll know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star", each letter corresponds to the first letter of each word in the song.

Comment: Did you google that? Just curious, nothing wrong with using your resources. I would have done the same.

Comment: Yeah I did, originally I saw the first ten and last ten letters were the same and tried to think of popular song lyrics to match. Came across multiple links searching the ten letters such as http://digitalusers.blogspot.com/2011/06/make-strong-password-in-just-four-steps.html

Comment: Looks like it wasn't too hard. :) I might use that on one of my friends tomorrow, I figured that it wouldn't take too long to find it. Puzzling Beta questions are super hard and still get answered super quickly.