# Scrambled Songs 2: What is the song this time?

Tags: cipher

Yeah... this is the sequel to Scrambled Songs which is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/scrambled-songs:).

This is to redeem myself from that really easy question:
Another scrambled song...

3684-4009-4010-4840-3756-4876-4262-3755-4279

A hint or two after the first week... answer by 3 weeks.

HINT:

> It's not hexadecimal

HINT 2:

> Convert it to a base between 11 and 20

Comment: Observation: all your four-digit strings begin with either 3 or 4.

Comment: I tried making it encoded-message, but that is marked as a synonym for cryptograms

Comment: @awesomepi - Thanks.  Is the message scrambled or in the correct sequence?

Comment: @Len It's in the correct sequence.

Comment: Google that and you get a negative number and two results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to Base 17, this is what you get:

> CCC DEE DEF GCC CGG GEE ECC CGF EDC

Those are the notes of a tune named **Row Row Row Your Boat**

Comment: Took you long enough ;)